# How to click on a button based on the presence of some text, in Selenium using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, delete-file

I have a test case where I am supposed to create an export doc to verify that the functionality is working fine. For every export doc, I am explicitly providing the doc title, as can be seen in the screenshot. Since the scripts will be running on a regular basis, before creating the doc, I want to check whether a doc with the same name already exists or not - and if it exists, delete it and then proceed with the creation part.

The export page is structured to list down latest created docs on the top. Its fine for me to just click on the first delete button encountered but to make it more robust, I am seeking to actually look for a doc with the required title and then click on the corresponding Delete button.

I am unable to think through an optimal approach as to how to click the Delete button when the doc is found (multiple docs with the same name may/ may not be present)

Any help on this is highly appreciated. Thank you!

[image: The screenshot lists down two duplicate export and I would like to delete both before diving into the creation process]

Comment: ```optimal approach as to how to click the Delete button``` What do you mean HOW to click?

Comment: There is a good example in the documentation about finding elements based on text: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html